# Why does my array loops forever?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

On this code, when I click **prev**, it loops like `54321 - 54321 -54321`. But when I click on **next**, it loops forever. 
I want it turn back to number 1 when the array is finished. I want it like `(next= 12345-12345-12345) and (prev=54321-54321-54321)`

Is there a way to do it?

```
<?php
    $ar = array(
        0  => "picture1.jpg",
        1 => "picture2.jpg",
        2 => "picture3.jpg",
        3  => "picture4.jpg",
        4 => "picture5.jpg",
        5=> "kalle6.jpg",
    );

    if($_GET['start']==0) {
     echo "<a href=index.php?start=". (count($ar)-1) ."> prev </a> ";
    } else {

     echo "<a href=index.php?start=". ($_GET['start'] -1) ."> prev </a>";
    }

    if($_GET['start']==0) {
     echo "<a href=index.php?start=". (count($ar)+1) ."> next </a> ";
    } else {
     echo "<a href=index.php?start=". ($_GET['start'] +1) ."> next </a> ";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You don't have a loop anywhere, so your code can't loop?!

Comment: This is not everything, there is no loop which could loop.

Comment: The loop keeps like http://localhost/webshop/index.php?start=1

Comment: index.php?start=2, index.php?start=3, index.php?start=4, index.php?start=5   etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If index (`$_GET['start']`) is lower than 1 then previous should go back to last array element (5). If it is higher than `count($array) - 1` it should go back to first one (0).

```
$array = array(
    0 => "picture1.jpg",
    1 => "picture2.jpg",
    2 => "picture3.jpg",
    3 => "picture4.jpg",
    4 => "picture5.jpg",
    5 => "kalle6.jpg",
);

$index = $_GET['start'];

if ($index > 0) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?start=' . ($index - 1) . '"> prev </a> ';
} else {
    echo '<a href="index.php?start=' . (count($array) - 1) . '"> prev </a> ';
}

if ($index < count($array) - 1) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?start=' . ($index + 1) . '"> next </a> ';
} else {
    echo '<a href="index.php?start=0"> next </a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now It looks like this, but still no loop like 51234-45123-12345 when I click on next. It stops at number 5.

```
<?php


$ar = array(
    0  => "picture1.jpg",
    1 => "picture2.jpg",
    2 => "picture3.jpg",
    3  => "picture4.jpg",
    4 => "picture5.jpg",
    5=> "kalle6.jpg",
);

//PREV CLICK
if($_GET['start']==0) {
 echo "<a href=index.php?start=". (count($ar)-1) ."> prev </a> ";
} else {

 echo "<a href=index.php?start=". ($_GET['start'] -1) ."> prev </a>";
}

//SHOW IMAGE
$show_img = 3;
$num_img = 0;
for($i=$_GET['start']; $i<count($ar) && $num_img < $show_img; $i++) {
$num_img++;
echo "<img src=".$ar[$i]."/>\n";}

   for($i=$num_img; $i<$show_img;$i++) {
     echo "<img src=".$ar[$i-1]."/>\n"; 

   }

// NEXT CLICK
if($_GET['start']<5) {
 echo "<a href=index.php?start=". ($_GET['start']+1) ."> next </a> ";
} 

?>
```